# Camera in Android - can't get preview to restart? Don't know where pics are stored?

Tags: android, camera, customization, storage, preview

When should a call be made to startPreview on the camera after taking a pic?
Used the code in the demo:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Works to an extent, but I cannot figure out how to get the surface holder to refresh so it is ready for another snap.

Also, for the life of me, I can't figure out where the pics are going.  Also, is there a way to get them to go to the Gallery like the regular camera does?

Answer (score 0):

Introduce the `startPreview()` in your captureButton's `onclick()` and control it with a boolean flag.

For example, let the flag be `isPicTaken`. Every time you click a new picture it should be set **true** and when you start the preview, it should be set **false**. The code should look something like -

```
Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
captureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!isPicTaken) {          
            mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        } else {                
            mCamera.startPreview();
            isPicTaken = false;     
        }
    }
});
```

Note that `mCamera.takePicture` here uses all three callbacks, i.e, `(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback)`. The usage of last callback is given in the docs you have checked, rest two callbacks can be used like -

```
// Called when shutter is opened
ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() { 
    public void onShutter() {
        isPicTaken = true;  //set flag true only when shutter is called.
        // 
    }
};

// Handles data for raw picture
PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //
    }
};
```

Check [this example](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html) and you can even use it for reference if you are completely new. Hope this helps.